# Sending Emails without User Intervention (no Intents) in Android

Tags: android

I want to send the mail directly and without Intent .
I 've downloaded the necessary files ,
Add to my library .
But when I click on the submit button
The program is stopped .
I do not know what's the problem ?

java code:

```
package com.kpbird.sendemail;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SendEmail extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Mail m = new Mail("<USER EMAIL>", "<PASSWORD>"); 
            String[] toArr = {"<EMAIL-1>", "<EMAIL-2>"}; 
            m.setTo(toArr); 
            m.setFrom("<EMAIL>"); 
            m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
            m.setBody("Email body"); 
            try { 
              m.addAttachment("/sdcard/bday.jpg"); 
              if(m.send()) { 
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
              } else { 
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
              } 
            } catch(Exception e) { 
              Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
            } 
        }
    });

}
 }
```

I also have a file Mail.java

```
package com.kpbird.sendemail;
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String _pass;

private String[] _to;
private String _from;

private String _port;
private String _sport;

private String _host;

private String _subject;
private String _body;

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private Multipart _multipart;


public Mail() {
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    _user = ""; // username
    _pass = ""; // password
    _from = ""; // email sent from
    _subject = ""; // email subject
    _body = ""; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
    // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}


public Mail(String user, String pass) {
    this();

    _user = user;
    _pass = pass;
}

 public void setTo(String[] toArr){
     _to = toArr;
 }

 public void setFrom(String from){
     _from = from;
 }
 public void setSubject(String subject){
     _subject = subject;
 }

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
            && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
            && !_body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);

        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if (_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if (_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
    return _body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
    this._body = _body;
}
  //    static {   
   //        Security.addProvider(new com.indianic.email.JSSEProvider());   
   //    }  

    // more of the getters and setters É..
 }
```

In my program .

LogCat is:

```
02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kpbird.sendemail.Mail
02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):    at com.kpbird.sendemail.SendEmail$1.onClick(SendEmail.java:23)
02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
 02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
 02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
 02-03 15:40:56.957: E/AndroidRuntime(19523):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: which is line number 23 in "SendMail.java" file

Comment: String[] toArr = {"<EMAIL-1>", "<EMAIL-2>"};

Comment: i edited my answer. please check. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Right click your Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export`

After reaching here, libraries what you have used, "select" those libraries and move them to top of list. i.e suppose you have used "xyz.jar" file then following will be your sequence.

[x] xyz.jar
[x] Android x.x
[x] Android Dependencies
....

Save changes and rebuild your project after cleaning it.

**Suggestion**

I think **Mail** class name is conflicting. Try to change name of your class with **MyMail** and try.

Comment: Well is there a `Mail` class in android ? I don't think so or there is ?

Comment: I add 3rd party library .:mail.jar ,additional.jar,activation.jar,I put my full code

Comment: I do not think the problem is the class name .
I think there is a problem of line 21 to 23 .
Can I
Mail m = new Mail ("maria@gmail.com", "aaaa");
I use the webmail?